# instllation of mongodb server and client on fedora20

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb server on fedora20.
Then I have used admin database.
In admin database I created company database.
I created user emp with readWrite priviliges.
When I try to connect with mongodb server from another machine as client as folllows

```
mongo -u emp -p emp123 ipaddress of mongodb server:port no
```

it says "authentication fail".

I don't want to connect to admin or test database.
I want to connect to company database.
Can anybody explain me steps to install client and server of mongodb on fedora20

Answer (score 0):

mongo command-line has an option to specify the database against which you want to authenticate. In your case, since you created user in admin database, you should use  "--authenticationDatabase admin" on the command-part in addition to the other parameters.